# How to solve duplicate records in my rails app

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3.2, formtastic, update-attributes, link-to-function

We use Formtastic and built add_fields / remove_fields for one to many association models based on this [railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2). Now we are encountering a duplicate entries problem. Say, after we create a new project, and then edit this project with 3 tasks loaded, if I add one more task when editing, this new added task is duplicated in database.

We also use update_attributes to check validation and AJAX to submit the form and run the process in the background job in sidekiq.

And I found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18946479/ror-nested-attributes-produces-duplicates-when-edit), but I'm using rails 3.2. Not sure what I can do for this case...

Has anyone met this problem before? I'm now trying to post my codes here.(too complicated to simplify posting here hehe)

**UPDATE**
So after a long investigation of this problem, we found the double entry is caused by submitting AJAX twice.

Comment: `validates_uniqueness_of` in your Model might help:  http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_uniqueness_of

Comment: @Kelseydh we also tried this similar solution, add index to multiple columns but it doesn't solve the original problem. but this is a good idea to detect double entries.

Answer (score 0):

As answered in the other StackOverflow question you mentioned, you have to send the `id` attribute for each task while sending the parameters via ajax.